# Bold text if user has not viewed post

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a home page for logged in users which lists titles to various posts that have been submitted.  The question I have, is how do I make the title for each post **bold** if the user has not viewed it?

I have come up with the idea of creating a new db table and storing the userid and postid when the user clicks the link, but haven't come up with a way to translate that into bold/unbold links on the homepage.

Comment: Hi, are you looking for a UI suggestion, like css or other layouting tip? If so please describe or show the markup you are currently using to render the post list. If your are looking for a db design tip, also describe better the db structure you currently have.

Answer (score 3):

What do the URLs for your application look like? It sounds like you may just be able to let the browser handle this with some simple CSS. For example, the following CSS will cause unvisited links to be displayed in **bold**:

```
a:link {
    font-weight: bold;
}

a:visited {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

You may want to add a class selector or something more specific so that this behavior only targets the links in question, but hopefully this gets the general idea across.

Comment: The website I am working on is made for mobile devices, which is why I am trying to have the DB store whether or not the user has viewed the post rather than rely on the browser's cache. Is there a way that I can apply this CSS to the links based on that?

Comment: @Kevin You could use the result of [Joe's query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146471/bold-text-if-user-has-not-viewed-post/5146531#5146531) to add a class to unvisited links (e.g., `.unvisited`), then use the following CSS: `a.unvisited { font-weight: bold; }`

Answer (score 2):

On the SQL side, you could identify the unviewed posts like this:

```
SELECT p.postid, p.post_title,
       CASE WHEN pv.userid IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsPostUnviewed
    FROM posts p
        LEFT JOIN PostsViewed pv /* This is new new DB table you mentioned */
            ON p.postid = pv.postid
                AND pv.userid = @YourUserId
```